# Hilt lazy singleton with dependency at runtime

Tags: android, dependency-injection, runtime, dagger-hilt, lazy-initialization

I have the following scenario:

- A `FooRepo` that do an *API Rest* communication to get an **ID**
- A `BarRepo` with `AnotherRepo` as a dependency and also the **ID** I got from `FooRepo` at runtime as dependency.

I want `BarRepo` asking only for what it needs in its constructor, so no *Factory*, *Holder* or similar, also I want `BarRepo` to persist until another request to create an instance with a different ID is made or Hilt is cleared. I also want the same thing for the classes that have `BarRepo` as dependency (no *Holder*, *Factory*...)

The code of what I want to achieve:

**The repositories**

```kotlin
class FooRepo {
    fun createFoo() {
        val id = api.createFoo()
        // Here I want to tell Hilt to create BarRepo with this ID so any class
        // that ask for BarRepo as a dependency can now get an instance, and that
        // instance should persist until another request to create BarRepo with a
        // different ID is made. I don't want to pass any Factory or Holder to 
        // any class, just the BarRepo instance, I want to keep that logic in the
        // Hilt modules.
    }
}

class BarRepo @Inject constructor(
    private val fooRepo: FooRepo,
    private val id: Int,
)
```

**Hilt module**

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class NetworkModule {
    
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideFooRepo(): FooRepo {
        return FooRepo()
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideAnotherRepo(): AnotherRepo {
        return AnotherRepo()
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideBarRepo(@Assisted id: Int, anotherRepo: AnotherRepo) : BarRepo {
        // [fooRepo] is already provided so is not a problem
        // [id] can be provided only at runtime so [BarRepo] instantiation should
        // be delayed (lazy)
        return BarRepo(anotherRepo, id)
    }
}
```

If everything I asked is not currently possible with Hilt I would like at least to know the best approach for this.

Thank you in advance.